# Titanium Mobile / Javascript Json call not working

Tags: php, javascript, json, titanium

I am using JSON to communicate with a PHP script I have running on a remote server.
The application makes a call to the script and sends some data around.

I do not have much experience with JSON and I seem to be doing something wrong and I just can't find what it is.

Tried finding my problem on google and stackoverflow, but the thing is I don't really know what the problem is as I do not have the said experience with JSON.

Here goes:

In a loop I am generating a temporary list which is being pushed to an array:

```
    
    var tmpData = {
       rowType: row.rowType,
       isChecked: row.isChecked,
       position: i
    };

    resultArr.push(tmpData);
```

This `resultArr` results in :

```
{
        isChecked = 1;
        position = 0;
        rowType = phone;
    },
        {
        isChecked = 1;
        position = 1;
        rowType = mobilephone;
    },
        {
        isChecked = 1;
        position = 2;
        rowType = email;
    },
        {
        isChecked = 0;
        position = 3;
        rowType = sms;
    }
```

The above is being send to a remote php script:

```
xhr.send({data : JSON.stringify(resultArr) });
```

Result in PHP:

```
[data] => [
{\"rowType\":\"type1\",\"isChecked\":true,\"position\":0},
{\"rowType\":\"type2\",\"isChecked\":true,\"position\":1},
{\"rowType\":\"type3\",\"isChecked\":true,\"position\":2},
{\"rowType\":\"type4\",\"isChecked\":false,\"position\":3}]
```

In the PHP script I need this data to save it in a database.
However upon `json_decode` on the `$_POST["data"]` or `$_POST` the result is empty.

So my question, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your $_POST['data']-variable, the quotes are escaped (like this `\"`).

You'll have to run `stripslashes` on `$_POST['data']` to decode it correctly. Tried it, and my final code looked like this:

```
$json = '[
{\"rowType\":\"type1\",\"isChecked\":true,\"position\":0},
{\"rowType\":\"type2\",\"isChecked\":true,\"position\":1},
{\"rowType\":\"type3\",\"isChecked\":true,\"position\":2},
{\"rowType\":\"type4\",\"isChecked\":false,\"position\":3}]';

$decoded = json_decode( stripslashes($json) ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I don't know why but I did not think of that at all, so simple.. I always assumed `stripslashes` was only working on strings, but a JSON string is a string.. Thanks so much!